# bash, I have a folder I am taking files from it and sending each line to a part of an xml with echo

Tags: bash, unix, cygwin

This is a small portion of my script. I know it doesn't work but the results are close to what I need. tmp has the contents like this;

```
C:\xxx\DXF FILES\20136210.SLDPRT
C:\xxx\DXF FILES\4_2-1.igs
C:\xxx\DXF FILES\423843.prt.1
C:\xxx\DXF FILES\KC900.igs
C:\xxx\DXF FILES\MetalSheet_Pusher.step
```

I then use the script to reverse and strip the end of the line. I then need to put each line separately into my xml file. I have tried split and it gets me separate files but I need those echoed into my script such as echo `"<File>KC900.igs</File>"` I do not want to type each one in as there could be as many as 100 or more files in each tmp file. Sample of things tried.

```
#!/bin/bash
    set -x

cat tmp | rev | cut -d"\\" -f1 | rev > 1
split -1 1
while IFS= read -r line; do
    echo "<>$line</>" >> log.txt
done < 1
rm 1
```

I get the output I want with the while do but it is all lines and split would work if I can get each one and put it into my xml. this is the output of the while do loop. Any ideas or help is appreciated. I am still learning so give me a break please :).

```
<>20136210.SLDPRT</>
<>4_2-1.igs</>
<>423843.prt.1</>
<>KC900.igs</>
<>MetalSheet_Pusher.step</>
```

Comment: `awk -F\\ '{print "<FILE>" $NF "</FILE>"}' tmp`

Comment: That produces exactly what I have. I need it as;
<>blah</> then I pass this to a section of my xml.
then <>blah next in line</> I pass to another section of xml. Thanks for the shorter alternate though.